# touchpad and keyboard of my laptop randomly freezing

Tags: drivers, kernel, keyboard, touchpad, i915

I am experiencing a problem. Where the touchpad and keyboard of my laptop randomly freeze. Only suspending, by closing the lid and then opening it helps. It happens on every Linux distro I've tried. Even during installation from a bootable device. Logs are empty. It used to happen once in a couple of hours now it happens every 5 minutes.

After searching dozens of forums, I came across an [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263494), where this kind of problem is solved by adding an i915 (my laptop has an Intel Graphics card, btw) to early KMS modules. According to the solution, the reason behind that is "*harddisk is too fast and Linux not having a mechanism for properly waiting for all devices to be up, so you reach the graphical target, xorg tries to start, but the graphics card hasn't finished initializing*".

How do I add the i915 module to early KMS modules on Ubuntu? Or there is a better approach to solve my problem?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP Laptop 15-da3xxx 
Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic

UPD: if I plug in an external USB mouse it works fine. Then I turn on the screen keyboard, type `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse` and both the keyboard and touchpad start working again. Blacklisting psmouse doesn't help, because then the mouse cursor is not visible at all.

Comment: This might be a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/952231/how-to-enable-early-kms-on-ubuntu